# ¿Alguna manera de configurar la resolución con la que se ejecuta la terminal en C?

Tags: c, linux, consola, printf

Estoy haciendo el juego de los barquitos en C, y me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de cambiar la resolución a la que se ejecuta la terminal.

Cuando ejecuto el programa, la impresión no cabe ye se deforma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo que estirar la terminal manualmente a una resolución mínima de 103x24 para que aparezca la impresión correcta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Hay alguna manera de hacer que se ejecute en esta resolución directamente?**

Comment: Que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: @ArieCwHat uso Linux Mint Sarah.

Comment: La verdad es que tu pregunta es bastante difícil, aun para gente experimentada en Linux. Personalmente no tengo experiencia en Linux con C, pero quizá estos artículos te puedan ayudar [librería ncurses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), [ncurses en mint](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=135594) o cosas como [GTK](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/034.html). En windows es mucho mas simple :P , pero creo que debes buscar librerias que manipulen la ventana en el entorno gráfico que usa linux mint

Comment: No me supone un enorme problema no poder aumentar el tamaño de ejecución de consola, he buscado info toda esta noche y nada, aún no he encontrado lo que necesito. Muchas gracias por la info y seguiré indagando!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar secuencias de escape para manipular la terminal.

Por ejemplo, este comando de terminal cambia el tamaño del terminal a 90 columnas por 30 filas :

```
printf '\e8;30;90t'
```

Este programa en C invoca al comando anterior :

```
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
  execlp("printf", "printf", "\\e[8;30;90t" );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, simplemente me estaba rompiendo el tarro para encontrar esto.